# Что такое микроформаты?

Tags: css3, html, html5, css

Доброго всем времени суток. Расскажите что такое микроформаты в верстке, и как их писать, буду благодарен любой помощи!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала пара ссылок:

- [на яндексе](http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/?id=1111670).
- [на гугле](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=ru&answer=146897).
- [и классическая на вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82).

Грубо говоря - это определенные соглашения о том, как располагать данные в коде html страницы. И поэтому, боты и краулеры могут быстро и, самое главное, **однозначно** парсить такие вложения.

Comment: Спасибо! буду разбираться